# 'EXTEND_ESLINT' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslintrc, prettier-eslint

'EXTEND_ESLINT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I'm having this problem. Before I was using ubuntu and everything was working well now I just  moved to window 10 and start facing this problem in same project.

Anyone have idea why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

For windows bash you would need to use *SET* command:
`npm set EXTEND_ESLINT=true`